# Swift: Pause endless scrolling background (i.e. infinite loop)

Tags: swift, loops, sprite-kit, sprite, pause

In my game I would like certain things to pause when the "endGame" function is called, while other things stay running. I have been able to accomplish this for most actions by using the "paused" boolean, but I can't get it to work for my scrolling background. I know the problem has to do with how the background action is contained in a for loop, but I'm not sure how to get around this. Here is an example of my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var sun = SKSpriteNode()
var background = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun")
    sun.zPosition = -2
    sun.setScale(0.8)
    sun.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.632, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.90)
    let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: NSTimeInterval(10))
    let rotateForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate)
    sun.runAction(rotateForever)
    addChild(sun)

let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")
    backgroundTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest

    let moveBackground = SKAction.moveByX(-backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.004 * backgroundTexture.size().width * 2.0))
    let resetBackground = SKAction.moveByX(backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0.0)
    let moveBackgroundForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBackground,resetBackground]))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 4.0 + self.frame.size.width / ( backgroundTexture.size().width ); ++i {
        background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
        background.setScale(0.5)
        background.zPosition = -1
        background.position = CGPointMake(i * background.size.width, backgroundVert)
        background.runAction(moveBackgroundForever)
        addChild(background)
    }
}

func endGame {
sun.paused = true
background.paused = true
}
}
```

In this example the "paused" boolean works perfectly for the rotating SKSpriteNode called "sun", but it doesn't work for the background. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is create 1 `SKNode` for your background sprites,  add all the background nodes to this node, then add the master node to your scene.  Then, when you need to pause,  you only pause the master node, and the master node will then pause all of its children

```
for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 4.0 + self.frame.size.width / (backgroundTexture.size().width ); ++i {
    var background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
    background.setScale(0.5)
    background.zPosition = -1
    background.position = CGPointMake(i * background.size.width, backgroundVert)
    background.runAction(moveBackgroundForever)
    self.background.addChild(background)
}
addChild(background)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating multiple backgrounds in the for loop. But you are pausing only one.